# How To Find The sqrt Of A Negative Number In Python

Tags: python, math, python-import

When I enter a negitive number it gives me NaN (not a number) as an answer

```
import math
x = int(input("Enter a number"))
x = math.sqrt(x)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square roots of negative numbers are complex numbers, so you'll need the `cmath` (*complex* math) module for that:

```
>>> import cmath
>>> cmath.sqrt(-1)
1j
>>> cmath.sqrt(1 - 2j)
(1.272019649514069-0.7861513777574233j)
```